# can not mock final class using power mock

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I'm trying to mock the final class using power mock but getting "Cannot mock/spy class com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob\nMockito cannot mock/spy because :\n - final class" below is the code which i am trying

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({CloudBlockBlob.class})
@PowerMockIgnore({ "org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*" })
public class Test {

    @org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
    public void test() throws IOException, StorageException {
       CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = PowerMockito.mock(CloudBlockBlob.class);
       when(cloudBlockBlob.downloadText()).thenReturn("hello");
    }
}
```

and the gradle dependencies are as below:

```
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.13'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito2', version: '2.0.0'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: '2.0.7'
```

Comment: try this then: https://dzone.com/articles/mock-final-class

Comment: Aren't you accidentally mixing up JUnit 4 and 5? It seems like you wanted JUnit 4, but your test method is annotated with `@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`.